# Why useragents are different in UIWebview and Safari Browser ?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I wanted to know why user-agent call is different in UIWebview inside the application and in safari browser ?
And also since I am using UIWebView in my application can I use apple pay which is already on the webpage of the UIWebView or Do I need to use Passkit for it ?

Answer (score -1):

Safari is built by Webkit - http://www.apple.com/au/safari/[Apple doc on Safari](http://www.apple.com/au/safari/)

As for apple pay - you can use Java, CSS etc. to access and/or create the Apple Pay session. Apple have lots of guidance docs on the matter

1. [Apple Pay Session](https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs/applepaysession)
2. [Apple Pay JS](https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs)

Hope this gives you some guidance

Comment: so when I do user-agent call why it is different in UIWebview inside the application and in safari browser ?

Comment: 1- It looks like you're branching off into another question. To keep the "mods" happy, I'd recommend you asking a new question.
2 - That code is unintelligible and unreadable. Use the code tags available to make it a bit nicer to read.

Comment: and I am not using WebKit instead I am using UIKit,